# Text size proportional to the size of the image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I want that the size of my text to be proportional to the size of my image

I wanna do it in this code...

```
extension UIImage {
    func withText(text: String) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        drawInRect(rectangle)

        let fontSize = text.characters.count > 200 ? 10 : 14
        let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(CGFloat(fontSize))

        let paragraphAttributes = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphAttributes.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
        paragraphAttributes.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphAttributes
        ]
        (text as NSString).drawInRect(rectangle, withAttributes: attributes)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add screen shot of what output you are expecting.